# Connection Strings - MVC Entity Framework - Database First

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string, database-first

Can anyone suggest how I could programatically switch debug and live connection strings?

I've seen other people have passed an EntityConnection to the constructor from the controller like this :

```
private XYZDatabase db = new XYZDatabase(ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["XYZDatabase-TEST"].ConnectionString);
```

but it still requires manually changing it? is there a way to use

`System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` or similar
to switch it automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayende has a post that addresses this issue.

http://ayende.com/blog/135169/frictionless-development-web-config-and-connection-strings

Answer (score 0):

In my software I just have 2 connection strings of the same name in my app.config and comment/uncomment to switch between configurations.

Another method is that you could create a static property in your solution (.asax file?) and just use that to swap between XYZDatabase-TEST and XYZDatabase when you are fetching ConnectionStrings.

Answer (score 0):

Add connection string to your Web.config like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="XYZDatabase-TEST" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=XYZDatabase-TEST";integrated security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then open you Web.Release.config and add

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="XYZDatabase-TEST"
        connectionString="Data Source=OTHERSERVER;Initial Catalog=XYZDatabase-TEST;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
        xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Now, everytime you will publish you application to deployment server using **Release** configuration it will use the connection string from web.release.config

Note that this transformation will not work locally when you debug. You must publish to run the web.config transformation.